# how to find duplicate values and then print the information about them in dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to find duplicate person i.e. `'Tom'` and print information about him :

```
people = {
    '1': {
        'name': ['Tom'],
        'Programs': ['Python++.Java']
    },
    '2': {
        'name': ['Bill'],
        'Programs': ['English, math, science']
    },
    '3': {
        'name': ['Tom'],
        'Programs': ['Python++.Java']
    },
    '4': {
        'name': ['Sam'],
        'Programs': ['English, math, science']
    },
}
```

Comment: Your question currently doesn't give enough information. Please specify in which language you are asking and how should be the output ?

Comment: language is python, the output should be "duplicate person is 3, name: Tom, Programs: Python++.Java" or something like that

Comment: What if there are more than one duplicate? You want to print the last one ?  Are all the duplicates also have same `'Programs'` ?

Comment: there is Tom two times and I need information only about Tom i.e. person who is two times in the dict

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
used_names = []

for key in people.keys():
    name = people[key]["name"][0]

    if name not in used_names:
        used_names.append(name)
    else:
        print(f'Duplicate person is {key}' + ', ' + people[key]["name"][0] + ', ' + ' '.join(people[key]["Programs"]))
```

Comment: thanks a lot! <3

Comment: If the answer helped you, please, mark it as accepted. It really helps other people to find answers for the same questions and understand, if their problems were already solved or not.